# Can I link node@6 by force?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

Is it ok to link `node@6` by force?

```
$ which node
$ echo $?
1

$ brew link node
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node

$ brew search node
leafnode          llnode            node              node-build        node@0.10         node@0.12         node@4            node@5            node@6 ✔          nodebrew          nodeenv           nodenv
Caskroom/cask/mindnode-pro          Caskroom/cask/node-profiler         Caskroom/cask/nodebox               Caskroom/cask/nodeclipse            Caskroom/cask/printnode             Caskroom/cask/soundnode

$ brew link node@6
Warning: node@6 is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
```

---

Edit:

I went ahead and did it:

```
$ brew link node@6 --force
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node@6/6.9.5... 7 symlinks created
```

`node` and `npm` work fine now.
Scary warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may (I have) run into some Cellar issues..

What is the output you got from brew doctor?

I had this when executing `brew doctor`:

Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
`brew link <formula>` will cause other formulae to detect them during
the `./configure` step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

I had to execute `brew unlink node@6` for it to return 'your system is ready to brew'.

Comment: What `./configure` step??

Answer (score 7):

I ran in to the same problem and followed the advice of `brew info node@6` and added `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@6/bin:$PATH` to my .bash_profile. All the command line tools worked as expected.

(I've actually removed that line for my .bash_profile now and added an alias to set the path manually when I need it.)